# How to install usbip vhci_hcd drivers on an AWS EC2 Ubuntu Kernel Version

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel, compiling, amazon-ec2

It took me a while to figure out the problem, but I've been stuck and can't seem to find a solution to this.

So basically I want to connect a local USB to a AWS EC2 Instance, and the way to do it on linux is through `usbip`, but the problem now lies with EC2 Kernel Instances, they dont have the drivers installed by default, and drives need the exact specs to be loaded on the system.

Now, I have been trying to manually compile the drivers but I haven't managed to successfully accomplish that, the reason being is that the system does not compile the specific `.ko` module but at the same time, the other `.ko` modules installed, are not supported by the kernel.

The steps I am following are taken from here on Ubuntu on how to build my kernel: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel

This is to pull the correct kernel version that is under use from the EC2, the other steps are:

```
ubuntu@:~$ sudo cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
ubuntu@:~$ sudo cp /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/Module.symvers .
ubuntu@:~$ sudo make menuconfig
ubuntu@:~$ sudo make modules_prepare && sudo make M=drivers/usb/usbip
ubuntu@:~$ sudo insmod drivers/usb/usbip/usbip-core.ko && sudo insmod drivers/usb/usbip/vhci-hcd.ko
```

but even though the module compiles, there are no .ko drivers, nor the ones compiled work.

Is there a way to make `usbip` work on AWS on a EC2 instance? Is there another solution to the `usbip` drivers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I got an answer to this question from someone at AWS Support team. Hope this answer helps someone else in need.

> You reached out to AWS Support, because you are looking to use usbip client on AWS EC2 instances, but found no required kernel modules (usbip-core, vhci-hcd) available on Ubuntu[18|20] AMIs. You would like our assistance to address this and find the way to have usbip working on AWS EC2 instances.

In my test environment in us-east-1 AWS Region, I launched test EC2 instances from the latest AMIs for Amazon Linux 2 (ami-0be2609ba883822ec), and  Ubuntu 20.04 (ami-0885b1f6bd170450c).

I found that Amazon Linux 2 has required drivers:

```
# uname -r
4.14.209-160.339.amzn2.x86_64
# modinfo vhci_hcd usbip_core | grep filename
filename:       /lib/modules/4.14.209-160.339.amzn2.x86_64/kernel/drivers/usb/usbip/vhci-hcd.ko
filename:       /lib/modules/4.14.209-160.339.amzn2.x86_64/kernel/drivers/usb/usbip/usbip-core.ko
```

But, I didn't find usbip userspace tools after enabled EPEL repository[1], and scanned for package which may have this binary:

```
# yum provides */usbip | grep bin
```

And proceeded with installation of it from a tarball I sourceforge[2]:

```
# yum install autoconf libtool libsysfs-devel glib*
# wget https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/usbip/usbip/0.1.7/usbip-0.1.7.tar.gz 
# tar -xzf usbip-0.1.7.tar.gz
# cd usbip-0.1.7/src
# ./autogen.sh
# ./configure
# make install
```

By default it's installed in /usr/local/bin which can be added to PATH with profile:

```
# echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin" > /etc/profile.d/path.sh && source /etc/profile.d/path.sh
# usbip --help
```

For Ubuntu 20.04, I found that the drivers are available in "linux-image-extra-virtual" and I have it installed with 5.4.0-58-generic kernel:

```
# uname -r
    5.4.0-1029-aws
# apt update
# apt install linux-image-extra-virtual
# find /usr/ -iname "vhci*"
/usr/lib/modules/5.4.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/usbip/vhci-hcd.ko
..
# find /usr/ -iname "usbip*"
/usr/lib/modules/5.4.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/usbip
/usr/lib/modules/5.4.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/usbip/usbip-core.ko
/usr/lib/modules/5.4.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/usbip/usbip-vudc.ko
/usr/lib/modules/5.4.0-58-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/usbip/usbip-host.ko
..
```

Added drivers to load on boot:

```
# echo "vhci_hcd" >> /etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf
# echo "usbip_core" >> /etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf
```

Then installed usbip:

```
# apt install linux-tools-5.4.0-58-generic
```

Then modified grub to boot with 5.4.0-58-generic instead of 5.4.0-1029-aws according to $menuentry_id_option in my /boot/grub/grub.cfg

```
# grep -A1000 submenu  /boot/grub/grub.cfg |grep menuentry
  submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-175c087c-0fe9-4d62-a38d-e5f8a66a5851' {
  ..
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-58-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.4.0-58-generic-advanced-175c087c-0fe9-4d62-a38d-e5f8a66a5851' {
  ..
vim /etc/default/grub
  #GRUB_DEFAULT=0
  GRUB_DEFAULT="gnulinux-advanced-175c087c-0fe9-4d62-a38d-e5f8a66a5851>gnulinux-5.4.0-58-generic-advanced-175c087c-0fe9-4d62-a38d-e5f8a66a5851"
```

Then updated grub, rebooted ec2 instance, and verified usbip and loaded modules:

```
# update-grub && reboot
# uname -r
5.4.0-58-generic
# lsmod | grep vhci
vhci_hcd               53248  0
usbip_core             36864  1 vhci_hcd

# usbip --help
```